API Request Works on Client but Fails on Next.js Server
I'm encountering an issue where an API request works successfully on the client-side but fails on the server-side in my Next.js application.
"use server";

export const searchPlaces = (async (query: string) => {
  
  try {
    const url = "https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText";

    const data = {
      textQuery: query,
    };

    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "X-Goog-Api-Key": process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
      "X-Goog-FieldMask": "*",
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      console.error("Error fetching places:");
    }

    const responseData = await response.json();

    return responseData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching places:", error);
    throw error;
  }
});

If i remove "use server", the fetch happens client-side and the response status is a 200. With "use server" response status is 500. What am i doing wrong?
Im expecting the response to also be 200.
